# Ho do I write a script to remove loose geometry from all objects?

Tags: python, scripting, vertices, geometry

I'm trying this:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
for o in bpy.data.objects:
    o.select = True
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='VERT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_loose()
    bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='VERT')
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    o.select = False
```

when I manually assign an object like `o = bpy.data.objects[3]` and then do every step manually in the python console it works. But with the loop it doesn't work. Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the active object:

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = o
```

and you should check wether the object is a mesh object:

```
if o.type == 'MESH': 
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple to do so, using `bpy.ops.mesh.delete_loose`. Here's how I'm using it, merging that into the OPs code:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'OBJECT' ) 
for o in bpy.data.objects:
    if (o.type == 'MESH'):
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = o
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')            
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.delete_loose(use_verts=True, use_edges=True, use_faces=False)
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'OBJECT' )
```